# Can someone help me understand this excerpt on the properties of the modulus

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> The relationship of congruence (for a fixed integer) is a relationship
>   of equivalence in $\mathbb{Z}$. Each class of equivalence contains all
>   the integers that have the same remainder in the division by m.
>   Therefore, there are $m$ classes of equivalence for each $m$.

This is refering to $a\equiv b\pmod m$. Can anyone explain to me what this means?

Comment: Do you know what an "equivalence relation" is?

Comment: @RobinCarlier In this context, not really.

Answer (score 2):

Let $m=5$ and look at the $5$ equivalence classes that partition the integers:
$[0]: \{...,-5,0,5,10,15,20,...\}$
$[1]:  \{..., -4, 1, 6, 11, 16, 21, ...\}$
$[2]:  \{..., -3, 2, 7, 12, 17, 22, ... \}$
$[3]:\{...,-2,3,8,13,18,23,...\}$
$[4]: \{...,-1,4,9,14,19,24,...\}$

If two numbers $a,b$ belong to the same equivalence class, we say $a\equiv b$.
When $a,b$ are in the same equivalence class, they leave the same remainder, so their difference $a-b$ is divisible by $m$.

Answer (score 2):

In mathematics, an *equivalence* relation $\sim$ is a relation between objects of a same set $S$ that satisfies the following properties:

- For all $x$ in $S$, $x \sim x$, is other words, $x$ is in relation with itself.
- For all $x$, $y$ in $S$, $x \sim y$ implies that $y \sim x$. In other words, the relation is symmetric.
- For all $x, y, z$ in $S$, if $x \sim y$ and $y \sim z$, then $x \sim z$. In other words, the relation is transitive.

In such a setting, one calls a set of the form $\{y \in S,\, y \sim x\}$ for a given $x$ an "equivalence class", the equivalence class of $x$ is the set of elements of $S$ in relation with $x$ for the relation $\sim$.

What your excerpt is saying is that the relation "$\equiv$" of congruence modulo $m$ is such a relation (you can check it), and that there is exacly $m$ distinct equivalence classes, given by the possible remainders of the division by $m$ (they are $0,\ldots,m-1$).

Comment: Could you prove that?

Comment: Prove that this is an equivalence relation? Or that the remainders are in $1$-$1$ correspondence with the classes?